# Inequalities involving exponents and linear terms

Tags: inequality

I want to know of techniques that can be used to attack a problem like this:

For integers $1\le s_1\le s_2\le...\le s_n$ that form sort of a redundant binary representation of a number $m$:

$1-2^{-s_n}\leq m=\sum _{i=1}^n 2^{-s_i}<1$

Prove that $\sum _{i=1}^n s_i\le \frac{1}{2} n (n+1)$

I think you can prove this with induction on $n$ given that a simple binary digit count of $m$ says $s_n\le r$ but the real problem I want to attack doesn't seems to have this structure.

$\sum _{i=1}^n 2^{-s_i}$ is a convex function so maybe there are techniques related to that?